# Change Plus Minus Quantity Selector for WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want change quantity selector style [default style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX3MY.jpg) into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyERl.jpg) new style.

I'm using [this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-add-ons/) product for quantity option. Can anybody help me?

Comment: [Use this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qty-increment-buttons-for-woocommerce/) plugin for your requirement

Comment: Hi, i already try that plugin, but it wont change any quantity selector in my website. i also ask that developer plugin. but dont have any answet yet. any other solution?

Comment: Can I check your website?

Comment: sure, this is the page http://abdelcuci.com/staging1/product/bookingpage/

Comment: need to add custom code for that plugin will not work because it is not woocommerce quantity field

Comment: alright, can you suggestion solution for custom code.

Comment: are you using any plugin for those number fields?

Comment: for that quantity selector. my using product add on. one of woo commerce plugin.

Comment: can you tell me that add on plugin

Comment: this one https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-add-ons/

Comment: I recommend you try like [this](https://css-tricks.com/number-increment-buttons/)

Comment: i tried that one. but not successful with it